# Can I use plupload to load multiple image files into a single image field

Tags: media, files

I have an image file field on my Drupal 7 site that allows users to add 4 images.  I would like to give my users the ability to load all 4 images at once.  I have discovered the [plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) module and plup library which should be able to let me do this.  However, I have yet to discover an configuration (including the media module) which allows me to do this.  How can I make this functionality work?

Answer (score 1):

After installing [plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) module and placing plupload libraries, create an image file upload field and select **Plupload** widget. Itz done.

Answer (score 0):

Add this js in your custom js file.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.autoUpload = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('form', context).delegate('input.form-file', 'change', function() {  
        $(this).next('input[type="submit"]').mousedown();
      }); 
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

It will automatically upload all the images on click of upload button using above Jquery.

for more information,look at this link. at http://drupal.org/sandbox/clivelinsell/1587560 .